# Как насчет шашлыка?

Tags: лексика, морфология, единственное-множественное-число

Слово "шашлык" во всех словарях не имеет множественного числа. Хотя в разговорной речи очень редко можно услышать: "мы были на шашлыке" и т. п. Как вы думаете, допустимо ли использование мн. ч. В разговорной речи?

Во многих словарях "шашлык" - блюдо на вертеле, шампуре из баранины (свинины, говядины). В словаре  Ефремовой упоминаются креветки и рыба. Как насчет шашлыка из курицы, семги, овощей?

Answer (score 12):

А как Вы это узнали в словаре? В толковых словарях возле слов *стол* и *шашлык* абсолютно одинаковые пометы. Форма множественного числа приводится, если есть особенности в склонении. У меня , к сожалению, словарь грамматических трудностей на работе. О том, что "шашлыки" - неверно, не знала.

---

Ищу, ищу - ни в одном словаре не нашла запретительной пометы. Или чтобы было написано: шашлыки - разговорное.

Comment: Может, они мотивируют это тем, то слово "шашлык" не русское? Например, татары, говоря по-русски, не склоняют такие слова, как "шурпа", "долма". Даже те, кто очень хорошо знают язык, говорят "варить шурпа", "есть долма".

Comment: Шашлык - дано обрусело, тем более, что исходная тюркская форма фонетически весьма далека от современного русского звучания.

Answer (score 10):

Если честно, странно, что не имеет. По крайней мере, в разговорной речи очень даже имеет. "Поехать на шашлыки", "жарить шашлыки" и т. д.
Просто не вижу причин для отсутствия у этого слова множественного числа.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, что тут тот же случай, что и с кашей, супом, или, как тут недавно обсуждалось, шаурмой.
Шашлык - кушанье, не имеющее счетной формы, а значит и множественного числа. 
Шашлыки - это не много шашлыков, это шашлык разного вида. 
Но при этом одну порцию, палочку (шампур) шашлыка или даже отдельный кусочек частенько называют просто шашлыком, тем самым придавая возможность существования и множественному числу. Видимо, все это под действием языка гостей с Кавказа, которые так придавали колорит изделиям своей кухни. В Узбекистане, где само кушанье не менее популярно, слышать о "шашлыках" не приходилось.

Полагаю, "шашлыки" пока не переросло уровня "не совсем нормативной" разговорности.

Comment: Не знаю, кому конкретно ответить. А те, к то ратует за множественное число шашлыков, как прнимат эту множественность? Что такое "пять шашлыков"? пять порций?

Comment: *Полагаю, "шашлыки" пока не переросло уровня "не совсем нормативной" разговорности.* — Кузнецов и Ожегов с Вами не согласны.

Answer (score 0):

Почти во всех основных толковых словарях упоминается слово "шашлыки" во множественном числе. В Ожегове есть "пикник с приготовлением шашлыков", в Кузнецове "мангал для шашлыков" и несколько других выражений. Ни в одном из этих словарей ничего не сказано о разговорном статусе этой формы слова.

Кандидат филологических наук Ольга Ляшевская в книге "Семантика русского числа" говорит:

> Среди обозначений "кушаний из нарезанных кусков" по-своему уникальное положение занимает имя *шашлык*, обладающее двумя параллельными рядами числовых форм (множественное число более характерно для разговорной речи), ср. **жарить шашлык / шалыки**... Однако было бы ошибкой считать его исчисляемым... Употребляя (в контексте неопределённого количества) имя *шашлыки* во множественном числе, говорящий представляет это блюдо таким же способом, как пельмени, фрикадельки или шкварки, т. е. как набор небольших кусочков или изделий, находящихся в тарелке в количестве, достаточном для того чтобы не было необходимости их считать.